# Calculate difference between previous and current record in Mysql

Tags: mysql

How to calculate the difference between current and previous record.

Here is the table example

```
| rid    | time                |    data |
|10000038| 2012-03-13 12:30:18 |     100 |
|10000052| 2012-03-13 12:30:18 |     120 |
|10000053| 2012-03-13 12:30:18 |     140 |
|10000038| 2012-03-13 12:20:18 |     160 |
|10000052| 2012-03-13 12:20:18 |     180 |
|10000053| 2012-03-13 12:20:18 |     160 |
|10000038| 2012-03-13 12:10:18 |     100 |
|10000052| 2012-03-13 12:10:18 |     160 |
|10000053| 2012-03-13 12:10:18 |     160 |
```

Here I would like to have the result as,

```
| rid    | time                |    data | DIf |
|10000038| 2012-03-13 12:30:18 |     100 | 0   |
|10000052| 2012-03-13 12:30:18 |     120 | 20  |
|10000053| 2012-03-13 12:30:18 |     140 | 20  |
|10000038| 2012-03-13 12:20:18 |     160 | 20  |
|10000052| 2012-03-13 12:20:18 |     180 | 20  |
|10000053| 2012-03-13 12:20:18 |     160 |-20  |
|10000038| 2012-03-13 12:10:18 |     100 |-60  |
|10000052| 2012-03-13 12:10:18 |     160 | 60  |
|10000053| 2012-03-13 12:10:18 |     160 | 0   |
```

Note: Look at the table, Every time there is three data dumped in the table with seperate resource id. How to find the difference?

Comment: What does "previous record" mean? That implies a sorting mechanism. MySQL rows don't have a reliable built-in order.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `LAG()` function which lets you know the value from the previous record.

In your case,

```
lag(data, 1) over (order by time) as previou_val
```

would show the previous data!

Comment: this is the smartest and simplest answer!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a diff column in the table. Then, whenever you are updating the table with new values do this

```
UPDATE 
   `tablename` 
SET 
    data = 120,
    diff = 120 -
    (
        SELECT prev_data
        FROM (
          SELECT data AS prev_data
          FROM tablename
          WHERE `id` = '1'
        )
       AS prev_data
    )
WHERE 
   id='1';
```

### Tested & WORKS

## [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/836f7/14)

Answer (score -2):

You can use PHP,
when you are looping through your result set, 
save the value in a temporary varariable. 
use that to compare to the next row assuming the data you get is an integer.

```
$previousRow = 0; //initiates value for preceeding row

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $currentRow = $row['data']; //gets current row
  //gets difference between the two variables
  $difference = $currentRow - $previousRow; 
  echo "\$difference = $difference<br>\n";
  $previousRow = $currentRow; //reassigns previous row
  //display otherfield
  //display $diff
 }
```